# The largest eigenvalue of AR(1) matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, spectral-radius, toeplitz-matrices

Let $M$ be a $n \times n$ AR(1) matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is

$$M_{ij} = \rho^{|i-j|}$$

with $0 < \rho < 1$. Is there an explicit formula to compute the largest eigenvalue of $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have a **Kac–Murdock–Szegö** (KMS) matrix:

- Ulf Grenander, Gabor Szegö, [Toeplitz forms and their applications](https://books.google.com/books/about/Toeplitz_Forms_and_Their_Applications.html?id=5SFsiYoLY14C), University of California Press,  Berkeley and Los Angeles, 1958.
- William F. Trench, [Asymptotic distribution of the spectra of a class of generalized Kac–Murdock–Szegö matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(99)00080-4), Linear Algebra and its Applications, Volume 294, Issues 1–3, 15 June 1999, pages 181-192.

Information on the eigenvalues can be found on page 182 of Trench's paper.