# The eigenvalues of a matrix composed of powers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

During my research work related to the convergence of estimates, I needed to calculate the eigenvalues of the following symmetric matrix.

$$\Sigma_{n\times n} := 
  \begin{pmatrix} 
   1 & \frac{a}{2} & \frac{a^2}{2} & \frac{a^4}{2} &\cdots & \frac{a^{n-2}}{2} & \frac{a^{n-1}}{2} \\
  \frac{a}{2} & 1 & \frac{a}{2} & \frac{a^2}{2} & \cdots & \frac{a^{n-3}}{2} & \frac{a^{n-2}}{2} \\
  \frac{a^2}{2} & \frac{a}{2} & 1 & \frac{a}{2} & \cdots &   \frac{a^{n-4}}{2} &   \frac{a^{n-3}}{2} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\ddots & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  \frac{a^{n-1}}{2} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &\cdots & \frac{a}{2}& 1
\end{pmatrix} $$

I tried to guess the answer using analysis on small matrices, but even with a $3 \times 3$ matrix it is difficult to cope. For $2 \times 2$ matrices, everything is obvious. The recurrence has not been compiled.

Comment: This is, up to a multiplication and translation, (i.e. taking $\Sigma' := 2 \Sigma - I$) a Kac-Murdoch-Szegö matrix. See [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1804/1804.08140.pdf)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2815525/339790)

Comment: @JeanMarie *Murdock

Comment: Oleg, are you sure the (1,4)-th entry is $\frac{a^4}{2}$?  Shouldn't it be $\frac{a^3}{2}$?

Comment: Compiled?  I don't understand that part.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo Thanks for the $k \leftrightarrow h$. No sympathy for the well-known media tycoon with the "h"